# Sorting the Dictionary with datetime key value to get smallest and biggest Key

Tags: c#, dictionary, datetime

I have created a dictionary with DateTime Key and DateTime Value. In my dictionary, all the Key and Value has the same Date with different Hour and Minute. Now I would like to sort the dictionary in ascending order by the Key to find the lowest DateTime with Hour and Biggest DateTime with Hour. I have the below code:

```
var slots = new Dictionary<DateTime, DateTime>();
slots.Add(DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Date + new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0), DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Date + new TimeSpan(9, 30, 0));
slots.Add(DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Date + new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0), DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Date + new TimeSpan(10, 30, 0));
slots.Add(DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Date + new TimeSpan(9, 30, 0), DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Date + new TimeSpan(9, 45, 0));
slots.Add(DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Date + new TimeSpan(11, 0, 0), DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Date + new TimeSpan(11, 45, 0));
        
slots.OrderBy(x => x.Key.Hour);
        
                    //slots.Keys.OrderByDescending(d => d.Hour);
                    //slots.ToList().Sort((a, b) => a.Key.CompareTo(b.Key.Hour));
                    //slots.ToList().Sort((pair1, pair2) => pair1.Value.CompareTo(pair2.Value));
        
    foreach (KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime> slot in slots)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Start Time : {0}, End Time: {1}", slot.Key, slot.Value);
    }
```

But I don't get the output sorted as required. from the below output I need the second row should be the third row and the third row should be the second row.

[image]

Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: Your milliseconds are off due to multiple calls to `.Now`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```cs
var slots = new Dictionary<DateTime, DateTime>();
slots.Add(DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Date + new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0), DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Date + new TimeSpan(9, 30, 0));
slots.Add(DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Date + new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0), DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Date + new TimeSpan(10, 30, 0));
slots.Add(DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Date + new TimeSpan(9, 30, 0), DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Date + new TimeSpan(9, 45, 0));
slots.Add(DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Date + new TimeSpan(11, 0, 0), DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Date + new TimeSpan(11, 45, 0));

//insert the result of sort to dictionary
slots = slots
    .OrderBy(x => x.Key.Date)
    .ThenBy(a => a.Key.Hour)
    .ThenBy(a => a.Key.Minute)
    .ThenBy(a => a.Key.Second)
    .ThenBy(a => a.Key.Millisecond)
    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value);

foreach (KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime> author in slots)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start Time : {0}, End Time: {1}", author.Key, author.Value);
}
```

Result:

```
Start Time : 8/21/2021 9:00:00 AM, End Time: 8/21/2021 9:30:00 AM
Start Time : 8/21/2021 9:30:00 AM, End Time: 8/21/2021 9:45:00 AM
Start Time : 8/21/2021 10:00:00 AM, End Time: 8/21/2021 10:30:00 AM
Start Time : 8/21/2021 11:00:00 AM, End Time: 8/21/2021 11:45:00 AM
```

Comment: you can add more ThenBy for considering minutes and seconds.